# How do I plot two Gaussians/normal distributions with 2 different means and 2 different standard deviations?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

This is probably very easy for someone with more experience, but I am trying to plot only two Normal distributions, but for some reason my Method plots 4, instead of 2.

I have:

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x],
        {μ, 6, 7}, {σ, 1, 2}],
  {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

which plots:

[image]

My intention was to plot $Normal(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $Normal(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$
instead of all the 4 possible combinations of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `Table`, notice that `MapThread[NormalDistribution, {{6, 7}, {1, 2}}]` is equal to `{NormalDistribution[6, 1], NormalDistribution[7, 2]}`. So you can do
`Plot[{##}, {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis] & @@ MapThread[Composition[PDF[#, x] &, NormalDistribution], {{6, 7}, {1, 2}}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps simplest:

```
Plot[
  {PDF[NormalDistribution[6, 1], x],
   PDF[NormalDistribution[7, 2], x]},
  {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

With the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

OR with less typing, especially when you have many such distributions:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[##], x] & @@@ {{6, 1}, {7, 2}}, {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

You can add `Evaluated -> True` as an `Option` if you want them in different colors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

It is not very surprising that this produces the four gaussians that it does, as you're using a square `Table` construction. If you want to keep an explicit Table command, you can use a more refined iterator, which you can find e.g. in the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) documentation.

> `Table[expr, {i, {i1, i2, ...}}]`
>
> uses the successive values `i1`, `i2`, ...

The naive try is then

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[pars], x],
        {pars, { {6,1}, {7,2} } }],
  {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

though of course that won't work: it will call `NormalDistribution[{6,1}]` instead of `NormalDistribution[6,1]`. This has an easy fix using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (the `@@`):

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[PDF[NormalDistribution@@pars, x],
        {pars, { {6,1}, {7,2} } }],
  {x, 0, 12}, Filling -> Axis]
```

I think this solution is the least scary in terms of the number of weird symbols involved, while it also generalizes well to situations where you have many such plots and don't want to type the full `PDF[NormalDistribution[]]` throughout.